# How can I call function from another file in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to collect functions common for pipelines in a separate file. I created directories' structure:

```
vars/
...commonFunctions.groovy
pipeline.jenkinsfile
anotherPipeline.jenkinsfile
```

commonFunctions.groovy:

```
def buildDocker(def par, def par2) {
  println("build docker...")
}

return this;
```

In pipeline.jenkinsfile I want to call buildDocker function. How can I do this? I tried simply `commonFunctions.buildDocker(par1, par2)` in the pipelines, but get MethodNotFound error.

UPD:

relevant part of pipeline.jenkinsfile:

```
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
            checkout([$class           : 'GitSCM',
                      branches         : [[name: gitCommit]],
                      userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: gitCredId, url: gitUrl]]
            ])
        }
    }

    stage("Build Docker") {
        steps {
            catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                script {
                    // here want to call function from another file
                    commonFunctions.buildDocker(par1, par2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you define a shared library? Did you use `@Library('...') _` in your Jenkinsfile?

Comment: @MaratC I tried `@Library('commonFunctions') _`, but get `ERROR: Could not find any definition of libraries [commonFunctions]
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed`

Comment: For shared Library you have to add this into Jenkins configuration and also need to maintain java like folder structure. See  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First try to load that file in pipeline.jenkinsfile like this and use it like this. So your answer would be this

```
load("commonFunctions.groovy").buildDocker(par1, par2)
```

Make sure you add `return this` to the end of groovy script which is in your case `commonFunctions.groovy` inside file

Comment: With this approach I get `NoSuchFileException: {PATH_TO_JENKINS_JOB}/vars/commonFunctions.groovy`

Comment: @lleviy then just remove ```vars/``` and try

Comment: your approach with `vars/` in path worked when I added Checkout step to my pipeline and `return this;` to the end of my groovy script (edited the question to mark your solution as correct). Thanks!

Comment: In my testing, i found it works (yay!) in the stage it's defined in, but goes out of scope in another stage (boo!). Still, I'm stoked to have this new way of keeping my pipes DRY without using a shared library!

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to @Dathrath's answer with some more detail. As commented above, it works in the stage it's defined in, but goes out of scope as soon as that stage closes.

But! If you define it at the global level - before the pipeline starts - it is in scope through the pipe's life!

example:

```java
// Jenkinsfile

def testScript

pipeline {
  agent any
  
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
          script {
            testScript = load('src/test_src.groovy')
          }
      }
    }
    
    stage('another stage') {
      steps {
        script {
          testScript.test_source('max'). // <-- outputs 'max' to the console
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the lines have to be inside `script{}` blocks.

And it's critical to add the `return this` line to the end of the script file - it won't work without it.

```java
// src/test_src.groovy

def test_source(String test) {
  echo test
}

return this
```

You only need one `return this` line at the end of the file, regardless of how many functions you define in it. (It's returning the script object to the pipeline scope.)

**Additionally!** In the same way it's described in [the book](https://a.co/d/1P9JHlZ) (and maybe the jenkins docs?) to define a `call()` function as the "default" function for a script, if you define `call()` in this script file, you don't have to call a member function to use it. Just the name of the script:

```java
// src/test_src.groovy
def call() {
  echo 'this is a call'
}
return this


// lets you call it this way in the Jenkinsfile:
steps {
  script {
    testScript() // <-- outputs 'this is a call' to the console
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a life saver, and totally makes jenkins awful 'shared library' approach irrelevant.

as an additional note, for maximum flexibility within declarative pipelines, the @Field annotation imported from 'groovy.transform.Field' make sit so your import is callable  throughout your pipeline. thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @zentechinc. I don't think shared libraries are awful, but they are overkill if you're only building one pipe. I'm not sure what you mean with the Field annotation, can you elaborate? It's worth mentioning that my solution works in a test pipe but it's not cooperating in a complex, real-world pipe; maybe your idea will help get me over this last hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also this plugin: [Pipeline Remote Loader](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin)
You do not need to use `checkout scm`

Here is an example from the documentation how to use it:

```
stage 'Load a file from GitHub'
def helloworld = fileLoader.fromGit('examples/fileLoader/helloworld', 
        'https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin.git', 'master', null, '')

stage 'Run method from the loaded file'
helloworld.printHello()
```